# How to pass arguments to a thread in rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

I have a closure which I cannot change, which I need to run in a new thread and to which I need to pass a variable. This is how I imagine the code to look like:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    // I can not influence this closure, but this is what it looks like
    let handle = move |data: i32| {
        println!("Got {data}")
    };

    let foo = 123;
    // This doesn't work
    thread::spawn(handle).arg(foo).join()
}
```

Equivalent code in Python is does work so I am wondering whether this is possible in rust and if so then how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just need call the closure like a funcion inside spawn, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c2f45ddf9cb5254a384bedd95330103

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [thread::spawn()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) indicates it expects as input a closure with no arguments. Therefore, you can't directly use your `handle` closure. However, you can create a new closure with no arguments that calls your `handle` closure like so:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn main() {

    let handle = move |data: i32| {
        println!("Got {data}")
    };

    let foo = 123;

    thread::spawn(move || {handle(foo)}).join();
}
```

Comment: Or, to avoid the new closure, declare `foo` before `handle` and move into the closure (removing the `data` argument and using `foo` as `data`)